# Why simple animation code for my wave function does not work?

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I am trying to animate the wave function of electrons in an atom. I wrote the simplest python code following whats given in Matplotlob documentation on animation, but it does not do anything. Can anyone help?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
import numpy as np
import math

angles = (np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 360, endpoint=False))
fig= plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, polar=True)
line1, =ax.plot([],[], 'g-', linewidth=1)

def update(theta):

    line1.set_data(angles,energy_band(3, theta, 3))
    return line1,

def init():

    line1.set_data([],[])
    return line1,

def energy_band(wave_number, phase_offset, energy_level):
    return [math.sin(2*np.pi/360*i*wave_number+phase_offset*np.pi/360)+energy_level for i in range(360)]

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=[i for i in range(0,3600,5)], blit=True, interval=200, init_func=init)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi, Please provide your code so we can figure out what went wrong.

Comment: Just added the related code in the question.

Comment: @BusBar What do you expect the result to look like?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your data. Firstly, you must call set_data with single numeric. Secondly, if you divide energy function with 100 you have got data in a good scale to show. Moreover I set limits of axis. Check how I modify your code:

```
line1, =ax.plot([],[], 'ro')# 'g-', linewidth=1)

def update(theta):
    line1.set_data(angles[int(theta)], energy_band(3, theta, 3)[int(theta)]/100)
    #line1.set_data(angles,energy_band(3, theta, 3)/100)
    return line1,

def init():
    ax.set_xlim(0, 2*np.pi)
    ax.set_ylim(-1, 1)
    #line1.set_data([],[])
    return line1,
```

Another thing is an interactive mode. It's usually a problem when matplotlib do nothing, especially working with jupyter notebook.

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

matplotlib.interactive(True)
plt.ion()
matplotlib.is_interactive()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the data you want to animate lies between 2 and 4, but the polar plot shows only the range between -0.04 and 0.04. This is due to the use of an empty plot for the start. It would require you to set the limits manually. For example,

```
ax.set_rlim(0,5)
```

This is the only addition needed for your code to work.

However, one might optimize a bit more, e.g. use numpy throughout and reuse existing variables,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
import numpy as np


angles = (np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 360, endpoint=False))
fig= plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, polar=True)
line1, =ax.plot([],[], 'g-', linewidth=1)

def update(theta):
    line1.set_data(angles,energy_band(3, theta, 3))
    return line1,

def init():
    line1.set_data([],[])
    ax.set_rlim(0,5)
    return line1,

def energy_band(wave_number, phase_offset, energy_level):
    return np.sin(angles*wave_number+phase_offset*np.pi/360)+energy_level


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=np.arange(0,3600,5), 
                              blit=True, interval=200, init_func=init)

plt.show()
```